# trying to boot to ESXi disc but it keeps booting to Server 03 disc

Tags: vmware-esxi

i have 2 drives in a poweredge server and have server 03 installed by default on disc 0 partition C.  i recently installed ESXi bare metal from scratch on the other spindle disc 1, with nothing else on this disc.  now when i boot it takes me directly to server 03 w/ no option to select ESXi.  do i need to change the boot.ini file to point to the other disc?  if so, what partition do i point it to for ESXi?  there were 4 Hypervisor partitions created when i installed it.  thx a mil.

Comment: Have you considered simply changing the physical order of the drives?  ESXi really was not designed to work in a multi-boot environment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good read for dual booting into ESXi and 2003. http://www.legacycode.net/2010/01/31/esxi-3-5-server-2003-dualboot/

Comment: wow great link.  more work than i counted on, but that pretty much answers my Q.  thx..